# Disable ActionLink without jQuery or Javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc

is it possible to disable an ActionLink with a style or attribute or something. I do not want uses to click on it if they do not have JavaScript enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add link using JavaScript on the fly.

```
<a href="#" class="dis" > I am disabled link which will be enabled later if js is enabled </a>
```

jQuery code to enable it if JavaScript is enabled:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dis").attr('href','http://example.com');
});
```

Comment: Erm. Thanks Vivek for your quick answer. I am sure your answer would work fine for someone with more knowledge than I have. All that happened was that the link did not work if javascript was disabled. A user would obviously think something was broken if he clicked on a link that did nothing. What I was hoping to do was disable the link and not just make it not work. Is there something I missed or perhaps misunderstood? Ah - perhaps you intended the class to make the text gray or something, to make it obviously that the link was not enabled. I will try that. Many thanks.

Comment: the above code will make disable. 
sorry I am confuse what behavior you mean with 
(not just make it work )

Comment: Hello Vivek. Sorry, for not being more clear. By "disabled" I meant make the text in the link looks an behaves as if the link was disabled. In other words it is "grayed out" and clicking has no effect. Your sugestion satisfied the "no effect" requirement but did not "gray out" the link. As I said in my previous comment, I should be able to change the text color to gray it out. Sorry for not properly explaining what disabled means. Anyway, all is well now, thanks again.